# WordPress Theme Hack - How Do I Call Specific Child Pages Only

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, themes

I'm going to try my best to explain this correctly :)

This question is regarding a Wordpress Theme Hack and php.  Currently we are using Coda Blue as a theme [see here](http://hothtactical.com).  Right now the jQuery slider is being controlled by li's that are the tabs of the slider (web design, social media, etc).  The tabs are created by making a page, and the content of the page will be in its respective slide.  The tabs are being called by this code:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="#<?=$post->post_name?>"><span><?php the_title();?></span></a></li>
```

Is it possible to have the "Our Work" link make a reloaded page with different tabs for the slider?  For example, if "Our Work" was clicked then hothtactical.com/our-work would load and a new set of tabs would appear above the slider, perhaps child pages of a the "Our Work" parent page.  If this is possible we would want the "Our Team" to load up different tabs as well.

I thought that all it would require is an if - then statement saying that if a certain page is loaded then call for its child pages to be loaded in as tabs, but am I under-complicating things?  Is there javascript changes needed in the coding of the Coda Slider to allow it to make a parent page loadable instead of it going to the slider?  I am fervently paying attention to this thread so let me know if you need any further documentation or code.

I am willing to donate to the cause of the individual that can help a brother out here.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Without having the theme to play with ($47 is too much for testing, sorry), it's hard to say. the only thing I can think of is to create subdomains with separate WP installs (or [WP MU](http://mu.wordpress.org/)) like work.hothtactical.com, team.hothtactical.com, begin.hothtactical.com and link to those from the header. HTH.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  It is already on a WPMU install, and hothtactical.com is a subdomain already of my main blog.  I wonder if it is possible to subdomain the domain that it is mapped too...

After investigating, I see that this line is controlling what shows up in the tabs is a query_posts statement.  Is there a way to set up a statement that identifies what page you are on and displays posts accordingly?

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what is going on... If query_posts determines what is in the tabs, then aren't the tabs created by posts, not pages? Either way, check http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts for info on working with query_posts.